# reference x is undefined on page 1

Tags: citing

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[twocolumn,epjc3]{svjour3}  
\smartqed  

\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\RequirePackage{latexsym}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\journalname{Eur. Phys. J. C}
%
\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here%\thanksref{t1}
}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}


\author{First Author\thanksref{e1,addr1}


}


\thankstext{e1}{e-mail: fauthor@example.com}


\institute{First address \label{addr1}
           \and
           Second address \label{addr2}
           \and
           \emph{Present Address:} if needed\label{addr3}
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}


Text with citations \cite{71}  \cite{9}and \cite{RefJ}.



\begin{figure*}

\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
%
% For tables use
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Please write your table caption here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
first & second & third  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
number & number & number \\
number & number & number \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
%\bibliography{}   % name your BibTeX data base

% Non-BibTeX users please use

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

the citation is not working. it is showing Text with citations [?] [?]and [?].
can anyone help me with the problem
??

Comment: have you run bibtex to generate the bibliography?

Comment: Where are the bibliographic entries with keys `9`, `71`, and `RefJ` stored? In `bib.bib`, by any chance? Did you run BibTeX? If so, do you get any warning and/or error messages (likely recorded in `\jobname.blg`)? If the answer is yes, what do the messages say?

Comment: @david yes i have

Comment: i have run it and it did not show any error

Comment: show your tex log from the above document (note it's not strictly an error but it is very odd and confusing practice to use numbers as \cite or \ref keys.

Comment: Package natbib Warning: Citation `71' on page 1 undefined on input line 49.

You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.
 Learn more
 main.tex, line 49

Package natbib Warning: Citation `9' on page 1 undefined on input line 49.

You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.
 Learn more

Comment: that is only a fragment (and not the bit I was looking for) also it is better to edit the question, code blocks do not work in comments.  But do you have an entry in your bib file with key `71` (as I say it is very unusual to have such a numeric key)